# How can I make a strtr with values coming from database

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following code:

```
 $books = $fetchPageContents->books;

 echo strtr($books, array('sacrifice' => '<a href="#"> sacrifice </a>','sacrificing' => '<a href="#"> sacrificing </a>'));
```

I want to transfer this data to a db for cleaner handling of the code. How could this be accomplished?

These are my thoughts (Please assume `$db` is connected):

```
$content = $db->query("SELECT keyword, link FROM keywords"); 

   while($fetch_content = mysqli_fetch_array($content)) {
     $keyword = $fetch_content["keyword"];
     $link = $fetch_content["link"];
}
```

This is the part where I'm stuck. I want to *push* the content into an array. But, the array is inside a PHP function. How do I *push* to the PHP array in a correct way?

Thanks...

Comment: create a container first, build the key pair keyword => link first, then feed it into the array

Comment: You can also use closures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it into a variable that you use with `strtr`.

```
$translations = array();
while($fetch_content = mysqli_fetch_array($content)) {
    $keyword = $fetch_content["keyword"];
    $link = $fetch_content["link"];
    $translations[$keyword] = $link;
}
```

Then use `$translations` as an argument to the function that calls `strtr()`.